# Reverting a form to its original values

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I am trying to code a cancel button that when it is clicked, will revert the changes made to the form and then close it. One idea that I had was on the form load event declare variables to store original values. However since that would involve declaring them as global, I did not want to go that route. With that said my question is: What is the best way to revert changes to a form without having to declare a bunch of global variables.

**EDIT:**

Hey guys thanks for the help but after researching I found the answer. Since i was storing all these form's control values into My.Settings, all I needed to do was use

```
My.Settings.Save()
```

on the accept button click event and

```
My.Settings.Reload()
Me.Close()
```

on the close button event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for the help but after researching I found the answer. Since i was storing all these form's control values into My.Settings, all I needed to do was use

My.Settings.Save()

on the accept button click event and

My.Settings.Reload()
Me.Close()

on the close button event.

Answer (score 0):

what is your general design of the form? if you have to close the form can't you simply close it immediately without saving?

in case you have data bound controls on the form you could do dataSource.RejectChanges eventually...

Comment: The form just consists of some textboxes, checkboxes, and numericupanddowns.

Comment: then close it without saving, why do you want to restore previous values if you are closing it anyway?

Comment: I just wanted to use the cancel button to cancel any changes made to the form. I use Me.Close() on the button click event to close the form but it still saves the changes made.

Comment: can you edit the question and show what you are doing in the form? At least where and how you save the data, the click handler of the close button and form load event for example...

Answer (score 0):

Saving the original values is the right idea.  Instead of saving them at the global level, you can save them in private variables in your form class.  You'll probably want to store them all in a single data structure -- a hash map would be a good bet.

Comment: in a bit more object oriented approach if you open the form to show the details of the object Person, you already have the Person business entity which holds all his data, simply not changing anything in such object and closing the form will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use DataBindings between some datasource/object and your form.  This would allow you the ability to 'rollback' potential changes using `RejectChanges`.

Here is more information on DataSet.RejectChanges (in this case the DataSet would contain your data).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.rejectchanges.aspx